# How does cxFreeze include internal project modules?

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

**Update:**

I suspect this is an error in cxFreeze as I understand this should
go automatically.

**end update**

**Update:**

I missed an error given by cxFreeze:

```
Missing modules:
? Test.MyClass imported from main__main__
```

**end update**

I'm not sure what the proper term is for modules within project unlike sys or PyQt, so I'm going with internal project modules.

I have some example code below where I recieve the error "ImportError: cannot import name MyClass." and I would love to know how to get cxFreeze to compile that 'Test.py' module.

Here's my main code:

Main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
#from guiObjects.MainWindow import MainWindow
from Test import MyClass

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Initializing the main window
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QMainWindow()
    #mainWindow = MainWindow(widget)
    test = MyClass()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Test.py

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

__init.py__

```
'''empty'''
```

Setup.py

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

path_platforms = ( "C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll", "platforms\qwindows.dll" )

includes = ["re","sip","atexit","PyQt5.QtCore","PyQt5.QtGui"]
includefiles = [path_platforms]
excludes = [
    '_gtkagg', '_tkagg', 'bsddb', 'curses', 'email', 'pywin.debugger',
    'pywin.debugger.dbgcon', 'pywin.dialogs', 'tcl',
    'Tkconstants', 'Tkinter'
]
packages = ["os"]
path = []

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {
                     "includes":      includes, 
                     "include_files": includefiles,
                     "excludes":      excludes, 
                     "packages":      packages, 
                     "path":          path
}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
exe = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    exe = Executable(
      script="../Main.py",
      initScript = None,
      base="Win32GUI",
      targetDir = r"dist",
      targetName="Main.exe",
      compress = True,
      copyDependentFiles = True,
      appendScriptToExe = False,
      appendScriptToLibrary = False,
      icon = None
    )

setup(  
      name = "Main",
      version = "0.1",
      author = 'me',
      description = "My GUI application!",
      options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables = [exe]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens when you run `setup.py` in a subfolder of where `Main.py` is located.
I now placed my `setup.py` in the same folder as `Main.py`. and changed my `.bat` file to `python ../setup.py build install`.

This seems to be a bug in cx_Freeze as it works fine for Python 2.7, but not Python 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Your test.py is wrong, you can't leave functions empty, try

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

and in setup.py mabye add "Test" into "includes"

```
includes = ["re","sip","atexit","PyQt5.QtCore","PyQt5.QtGui", "Test"]
```

Comment: I have tried that already. It results into a empty Test folder made in Library.zip. I suspect that the correct result should be that the Test.py file ends up as a compiled pyc in Main.zip.

Comment: Is there a `Test` folder somewhere that it could be finding instead of your `Test.py` file?

Comment: How about you rename the `Test.py` to something else like `Test1.py`
and then `includes = ["re","sip","atexit","PyQt5.QtCore","PyQt5.QtGui", "Test1"]`